# How to connect and read/write to Azure ADLS Gen2 or Blob Store using Shared Access Signature with Databricks

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-connect

I created SAS keys for my Azure Storage account, see image below.

Can someone show me how to connect to the Storage account with Databricks using the one of the Keys listed below:

[image]

I tried the suggested answer, however I'm getting the following error

[[image]

Any thoughts

[image]

The following shows the SAS token I used, but still getting the error
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy the **SAS** token and use the below code.

```
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.auth.type.<storage-account>.dfs.core.windows.net", "SAS")
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.sas.token.provider.type.<storage-account>.dfs.core.windows.net", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.sas.FixedSASTokenProvider")
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.sas.fixed.token.<storage-account>.dfs.core.windows.net", "?sv=...SAS_token")

spark.read.csv('abfss://data@jadls2.dfs.core.windows.net/outfromVS.csv').display()
```

Output:

| _c0 | _c1 |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 2016-07-28,CA,1,A,A1,7.92 |
| 1 | 2016-07-29,CA,1,A,A1,7.88 |
| 2 | 2016-07-30,CA,1,A,A1,8.0 |
| 3 | 2016-07-31,CA,1,A,A1,7.94 |
| 4 | 2016-08-01,CA,1,A,A1,8.0 |
| 5 | 2016-08-02,CA,1,A,A1,7.98 |
| 6 | 2016-08-03,CA,1,A,A1,7.99 |

Refer [this](https://docs.databricks.com/en/storage/azure-storage.html#language-SAS%C2%A0tokens) for more information.

Comment: Hi @JayashankarGS, I tried your suggestion, however I've updated the question with the error that I'm getting. Any thoughts?

Comment: Should I use the ```Blob service SAS URL``` or ```SAS token```

Comment: Need to give sas token. Change the path to `.dfs.core.windows.net` not `.blob.core.windows.net`

Comment: Hi Jay, changing the path to .dfs.core.windows.net worked. Thank you